# Zipped Columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two lists I want to create a pandas Dataframe with 3 columns whereby one of the columns contains a column generated by zipping two of the list. I tried the following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

S_x = [80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 600, 800, 900, 1000, 1200]
S_y = [800, 1000, 1200, 450, 80, 100, 60, 300, 700, 900]
S_z=list(zip(S_x,S_y))

frame4 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([S_x, S_y,S_z]), columns=["Recovered Data", "Percentage Error","Zipped"])
```

In the column S_z I want the elements to be tuples as they appear in list S_z while the first two columns they should be the way they are.  When I run my code I get the error

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 10), indices imply (3, 10)
```

I don't know what I am making wrong. Am using Python 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use np.column_stack, it automatically unzip your S_z and thus `np.column_stack([S_x, S_y,S_z])` become of shape (10, 4) instead. Do like this:

```
frame4 = pd.DataFrame({"Recovered Data": S_x, "Percentage Error": S_y,"Zipped": S_z})
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
frame=pd.DataFrame(zip(S_x, S_y, S_z), columns=["Recovered Data", "Percentage Error","Zipped"])
   Recovered Data  Percentage Error       Zipped
0              80               800    (80, 800)
1              90              1000   (90, 1000)
2             100              1200  (100, 1200)
3             200               450   (200, 450)
4             300                80    (300, 80)
5             600               100   (600, 100)
6             800                60    (800, 60)
7             900               300   (900, 300)
8            1000               700  (1000, 700)
9            1200               900  (1200, 900)
```

Comment: this is not working TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator

Comment: What's your python and pandas version? @MafeniAlpha, it worked for me

Comment: @MafeniAlpha that is my question as well ~ what is your python version

Comment: @ Bruno Mello Python 3.7.3  pandas 0.23.3

Comment: @YOBEN_S your solution doesn't work but you are claiming it is because of version of my python but I do not think so. zip shall create a tuple (x,y,z) I don't get the logic how it can print your displayed answer. Please cross-check if am wrong I shall upvote your solution

Comment: @MafeniAlpha this solution work on my side and on Bruno side as well, so please update your pandas, right now pandas version is 1.0.x, stay at 0.23.3 may cause some output different

Comment: @ YOBEN_S okay. shall upvote your answer now it says to wait as its locked. Thanks a  lot by the way